# 2 by 2 table (Class*Sex) using Titanic data from R package "titanic"

Tags: r

I am working on R system data from the R package titanic `install.packages("titanic")`. The name of the dataset is `titanic`.

I want to conduct a Chi-square test between Class and Sex. I think before doing Chi-square I need to come up with 2 by 2 table. How can I come up with a 2 by 2 table ? or how can I do Chi-square test considering the data structure.

Expected 2 by 2 table: letter represent number(frequency)

```
                         Sex
                    Male      Female

Class     1st        a          b
          2nd        c          d
          3rd        e          f
          crew       g          h
```

Answer (score 1):

So here is one way to do this using some base R functions and the `xtabs` function:

```
# Save local copy of data
dat <- titanic::titanic_train

# Add a dummy column (this will make sense later)
dat$num <- 1

# Now generate the contingency matrix as described
xtab_titanic <- xtabs(num ~ Pclass + Sex, data = dat)
```

This looks like the following:

```
      Sex
Pclass female male
     1     94  122
     2     76  108
     3    144  347
```

And because we have the object saved in R, we can use the `summary` method to conduct the chi-square test:

```
summary(xtab_titanic)

# Call: xtabs(formula = num ~ Pclass + Sex, data = dat)
# Number of cases in table: 891 
# Number of factors: 2 
# Test for independence of all factors:
#   Chisq = 16.971, df = 2, p-value = 0.0002064
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

Based on: https://rpubs.com/RajatShrivastav/titanicoperations

```
install.packages("titanic")
library(tidyverse)
library(titanic)


titanic <- titanic_train %>% as_tibble()
titanic %>% names()
titanic %>% glimpse()

p=xtabs(~Pclass + Sex,data = titanic)
prop.table(p)*100
chisq.test(p)
summary(p)
```

Comment: A lot of this seems unnecessary: what's gained by converting to tibble, or calling `names` or `glimpse`? Not doing those would save you having/loading all the tidyverse packages (or just load the ones that export the functions in use). And which of the last 3 lines will get the test they're looking for?

Comment: Good practice, the table that op provided clearly doesn't perfectly match the answer we are supplying both in names and in content see the class columns there are divergences, I prefer to use tibbles and finally there are only two functions making the test and it comes down to preference which one you prefer I personally enjoyed summary but the post I am basing my answer was using chisq.test so why not both, it is not like it was more than couple of seconds anyway

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I have just noted that you are using dataset **titanic_train** instead of **Titanic** of course in my question I wrote titanic instead of  "Titanic". My apologies, assist please.